# Scan input from file line by line

Tags: c++, scanf

the data is in the format

```
int int string
```

eg

```
1 2 Hello Hi
2 3 How are you?
```

How do I get the individual elements from it?

Comment: You tagged the question as `fscanf`, and yes, that is an appropriate way to do it.  Another option is `ifstream`.

Comment: I know but I can't figure out what the format would be because %d %d %s isn't working

Comment: What have you tried? Just tested here and it worked.. I just had to use a char array instead of std::string on the fscanf.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No, it doesn't.  `%s` stops at any whitespace.

Comment: @SiddhanthMaheshwari: Edit that comment into your question, it's the difference between zero effort and an acceptable question. (A good question would show the code, the results you got -- grabbing only "Hello", and what you wanted -- grabbing all of "Hello Hi")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to do this with `fscanf`, you want to use a `scan set` conversion, like:

```
int a, b;
char c[256];

fscanf(infile, "%d %d %[^\n]", &a, &b, c);
```

To scan all the lines in the file, you'd do something like:

```
while (3 == fscanf(infile, "%d %d %[^\n]", &a, &b, c))
    process(a, b, c);
```

`fscanf` returns the number of items it converted successfully, so the `3 ==` is basically saying: "as long as you convert all three items successfully, process them".

In C++, however, I'd prefer to use an iostream, something like:

```
infile >> a >> b;
std::getline(infile, c);
```

Usually, a line a file like this will signify some sort of logical record that you probably want to put into a `struct` though, so you'd start with that:

```
struct foo { 
    int a, b;
    std::string c;
};
```

..then you could overload `operator>>` to read that entire struct:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, foo &f) { 
    is >> f.a >> f.b;
    std::getline(is, f.c);
    return is;
}
```

From there, reading the structs into (for example) a vector could look something like this:

```
std::vector<foo> vf;

foo temp;

while (infile >> temp)
    vf.push_back(temp);
```

If you prefer (I usually do) you can remember that a `vector` has a constructor that takes a pair of iterators--and that `std::istream_iterator`s will work fine for the job, so you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<foo> vf {
     std::istream_iterator<foo>(infile),
     std::istream_iterator<foo>() };
```

...and the vector will initialize itself from the data in the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it